# Wait for Ajax call to finish for Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

I am fetching data from a server(via ajax) using 3 select dropdowns. I want to write an integration test where I need to wait for the ajax request to finish then select a value from the next dropdown.

So far I am waiting for some seconds before doing the next select but that's not reliable and not a good solution.

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that capybara(latest version) by default waits for the ajax to complete then run the next line in the code. I did not have to do anything, just one selection after the other.

```
select 'VW', from: 'trademarks-dropdown'
select 'Golf', from: 'models-dropdown'
assert_equal 200, status_code
```

Comment: Note:  Capybara doesn't actually wait for ajax to complete - it waits for the option element to appear.  It's a small technicality but important to understand since Capybara doesn't know about the requests the browser is making, all it knows about is what it can and cannot see on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara automatically waits for items to appear on a page when you ask it to interact with them.  If it is not waiting long enough you can either increase Capybara.default_max_wait_time or pass the :wait option to most finders/actions.

So if you are loading a select box by Ajax you can just do

```
select('Item that is being loaded')
```

and Capybara will wait up until Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for an option with that text to be available to select.  If that isn't waiting long enough for your apps response time you can do

```
select('Item that is being loaded', wait: 10)
```

which will then wait up to 10 seconds for the option to appear to on the page and then select it